# child process writing to socket - localhost sent an invalid response

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, express, tcp

I have this in a parent process:

```
import cp = require('child_process');
const k = cp.fork(file);

 app.use(function(req,res,next){       
      k.send('handle', req.socket);       
 };
```

and then I have this in the child process:

```
process.on('message', function (m, socket) {

  if (m === 'handle' && socket) {
    socket.end('foobar!!!');
  }
  else{
    console.log('nope');
  }

});
```

After doing some logging, I know that `socket.end('foobar!!!');` is getting called. But I see this error in the browser:

[image]

Anyone know how I can send a valid response with just a plain socket at my disposal?

**I guess I need to learn how to actually write a valid HTTP response, never tried that before.**

Comment: This example is relevant: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_example_sending_a_socket_object

Comment: It seems to just write to the socket, but it uses `pauseOnConnect` in the server config.

Comment: I filed an issue on the Node.js issue tracker regarding this question: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20644

Comment: Do you realize that just sending `foobar!!!` is not a valid http response?  Why not try sending an actual http response.

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought maybe Express wrote some of the headers for me beforehand.  Can you show how to write a valid response from scratch?

Comment: There's no express here. You took over and sent a plain socket to another process. Nothing has been sent yet.  I'm on my phone.  You can google a simple http response in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
socket.end('foobar!!!');
```

Your are just sending `foobar!!!` and that is not a valid http response which is exactly what your client error message is telling you.

Because you've passed this socket to another process and express has not yet written anything to that socket in the original process, you need to send a whole valid http response here.

An http response looks like this:

[image]

Credit to [this article](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_Basics.html)
 for the image.

So, a very simple http response could look like this:

```
socket.end('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nHello');
```

Comment: `\r\n` shant be necessary, it's never gonna be processed by a Windows browser lol, or is this for IE? :)

Comment: @AlexanderMills - I honestly wasn't sure, but when I looked it up, the HTTP specification requires `CRLF` between headers and twice between headers and content.